# How to change the selectable options in ManyToMany field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm developing an application where I have a User creating a Document with some general content. I set up the model so the user can share that document with other users through a ManyToMany field shown below. The problem I have is the ManyToMany field shows all the users on my site as possible collaborators - **whereas I want to only show them their team members**. How would I go about doing that?

**My models:**

```py
class Document(models.Model):
    ...
    collaborators = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="doc_collaborators")

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    team = models.CharField('team', max_length=50)
```

**My forms:**

```py
class CreateDocForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Document
        exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at', 'owner', 'slug')
```

Comment: show the file forms.py with which you show.

Comment: updated with the forms.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be to override the queriset when the form is initialized:

```
class CreateDocForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['collaborators'].queryset = User.objects.filter([some filters])

    ...
```

Another solution is to use third-party modules: [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/)